# push data in Array AJAX/NodeJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, node.js, ajax

When I selected a service from select input, I got a div created by JS as below:

```
<form method="POST" action="/booking/success">
// SOME CODE IN HERE.................................
<div class="col-12">
      <h3 class="service__title" name="serviceTitle">Service 1</h3>
      <p><span class="display__number">1</span> x <span>500</span></p>
      <p><b class="display__total">500</b></p>
</div>
<div class="col-12">
      <h3 class="service__title" name="serviceTitle">Service 2</h3>
      <p><span class="display__number">1</span> x <span>1500</span></p>
      <p><b class="display__total">1500</b></p>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-right" id="submitBtn" ><span>SUBMIT  </span><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
</form>
```

I create Ajax variable for using in Nodejs:

```
<script>
  <script>
    $("button[type='submit']").click(function (){
        var length = $('.service__title').length;
        var data = [];
        alert($('.service__title:eq(0)').text());
        alert(parseInt($('.display__number:eq(0)').text()));
        for(let i = 0; i < length; i++){
            data.push({
                title: $('.service__title:eq(i)').text(),
                quantity: parseInt($('.display__number:eq(i)').text()),
                subtotal: parseInt($('.display__total:eq(i)').text())
            })
        }
        $.ajax({
            async:false,
            url: "../booking/success",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "html",
            data: {data:data},
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        })
            
    });

</script>
```

and console log:

```
app.post('/booking/success', async (req,res)=> {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.body.data);
    res.render("success");
})
```

When I clicked Submit, my array "data" is undefined.

```
{ data: 
[ { title: '  ', quantity: 'NaN', subtotal: 'NaN' } ] 
[ { title: '  ', quantity: 'NaN', subtotal: 'NaN' } ]
```

Please help me!

Comment: Just a typo you didn't print value of `i` inside `eq` i.e :`'+i+'`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't define `dataType` as `html` in your `Ajax` request, because you send JSON data. You also don't have to specify `contentType`.

try with this :

```js
  $.ajax({
      async:false,
      url: "../booking/success",
      type: "POST",
      data: {data:data},
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

[When I pushed object into array for loop, my array was undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Slu7Q.png)

[But when i pushed normally, my array got an object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgpN6.png)

I think there is a problem in the loop :((